# sshd never accepts public key offer

Tags: ssh

I have used PublicKey logins on a number of my servers for months without trouble. I generated the keys on my client machine and copied to the server's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys using ssh-copy-id. All well and good until one machine stopped accepting key-based logins the other day. Obviously there has been a change, but the sshd_config is the same as it was and as the other server.

Running the connection verbosely offers the following:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/kapn/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256: <deleted for post>
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/kapn/.ssh/id_dsa 
<and so on until it asks for a password>
```

My sshd_config file

```
Port 2201
PermitRootLogin without-password
PubkeyAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
# All else is at default settings.
# With the exception of the Port, PubKeyAuthentication and PermitRootLogin settings, 
# I didn't intentionally change anything here.
```

Any thoughts on where to look for trouble? Is there data to be gathered other than via the -vv switch on ssh?

Comment: I think there's a lot more to your configuration or is this really it?

Comment: look in `/var/log/auth.log`. usually the problem is the owner and permissions on ~/.ssh directory and ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file (must be owned by the user and be not world writeable)

Comment: Check the logs on the server, in particular `/var/log/auth.log`, as you were previously advised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions. I checked `/var/log/auth.log` and after wading through the endless attack spam, I could see that it was upset about directory permissions:

```
Dec 30 17:51:24 kaos02 sshd[25533]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/user
```

I discovered that I had at some point set group write permissions on my home directory. Once it was removed, all was well.

Comment: For anyone coming here trying to understand where the `'bad ownership or modes for directory'` error comes from, I'm posting here because it took me quite a bit of searches to find it myself. This is enforced by the [`StrictModes`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#StrictModes) setting in `sshd_config`.  It's not recommended to disable, but it is helpful for troubleshooting.